# Very simple iPhone question. How to make UIPickerView with two columns?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have read other questions about creating a UIPickerView with two or more columns but cannot find the exact solution.

How is this done for the iPhone programmatically? How do you add static data? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make your controller (or whatever is controlling the behavior of the PickerView) support the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol.  Then, implement:

```
- (int) numberOfColumnsInPickerView:(UIPickerView*)picker
```

to return the number of columns you want, and

```
- (int) pickerView:(UIPickerView*)picker numberOfRowsInColumn:(int)col
```

to return the number of rows for each column, and finally:

```
- (UIPickerTableCell*) pickerView:(UIPickerView*)picker tableCellForRow:(int)row inColumn:(int)col
```

to setup each cell.

See the reference for [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) and [UIPickerViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDelegate).

Comment: The link for the decent code is example is not available. I deleted it from your answer

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent tutorial on this subject [here](http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-9-adding-multiple-columns-to-uipickerview/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dictionary or a couple of arrays holding your static data. For simplicity I will go with a very simple array.

You have to modify your view controllers interface definition to tell the program that your view controller can provide data and delegation to a picker view.

```
@interface NVHomeViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

Than just implementing a couple of methods will make it work however documentation should be checked for other methods that are optional but provides more customization and control.

```
@interface NVHomeViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>

NSArray *options;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    options = @[@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [options count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [options objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSLog(@"%@ selected.",[options objectAtIndex:row]);
}
```